# Need help debugging GWT - Jetty 'unknown realm'

Tags: gwt, jboss, jetty, gwt-rpc, gwt-hosted-mode

I am trying to debug a GWT application, but it seems I can't do it with jetty. Whenever I try to run it in hosted mode for debugging I get an 'unknown realm' 500 error message (nothing loads). I am doing this via eclipse. It is very uncovenient to have to compile everything to debug in the browser afterwards.

After compilation I deploy the war into JBoss (using EJB on the server). But compilation takes time and when the code has been turned into javascript, you can't really debug. How can I debug the java code? I am looking into the -noserver option, but I wonder if I could still do it with jetty. And if not, why not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two points in your question:

- using authentication in the embedded Jetty (I presume you have a `<login-config>` in your `web.xml`): see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4462#c5 (now that this bug is fixed, you only have to put the `userRealm` in the `jetty-web.xml` and you can now use `<login-config>` in your `web.xml`)
- using `-noserver` to debug GWT code: using `-noserver` you won't be using the embedded Jetty in DevMode, so only your client-side code will run in DevMode. Your server-side code will run within the server where you deployed the app, and you'll debug it as you would debug any other Java server-side code (i.e. launch your JBoss server in debug mode and connect to it *remotely* with a Java debugger). To use `-noserver` you have to make sure the `.nocache.js` and `hosted.html` files are served by your server, either by first compiling your GWT code and deploying it, or by using your server's app folder as the `-war`of the DevMode (so DevMode will generate the files in the same folder as the web server serves files from)

Answer (score -1):

Could you give a little background? Did you just started up this project or was it working and then something went wrong? Are are your run configs commands?

---

### EDIT

- Please be more verbose (i.e. GWT version, complete error message, web.xml), need something to work on.

Comment: No, I haven't managed to get it to work. The previous developer didn't either. I am developing a UI for an existing java app which has been developed by others and to be honest, and I have limited knowledge of configuring GWT because I've relied on Eclipse so far.

Comment: Try to deploy your GWT app in Tomcat / Jetty. Just copy your compiled output and put it in your /Root dir. Look at the logs to help you determine your problem.

Comment: In your deploy settings for your GWT app you can also set the debug level from INFO to DEBUG.